# Python: Match string with multiple patterns

Tags: python, regex

I have below string in variables

```
'''
                                 Messages  Retrans   Timeout   Unexpected-Msg
           INVITE ---------->         30        0         0
              100 <----------         30        0         0         0
              180 <----------         12        0         0         18
              200 <----------         12        0         0         0

              ACK ---------->         12        0
             INFO ---------->         12        0         0
              200 <----------         12        0         0         0
       Pause [         10.0s]         12                            0
              BYE ---------->         12        0
              200 <----------         12        0         0         0

'''
```

How can i get below regex match output with one pattern or min pattern.

```
[('INVITE', '---------->', '30', '0', '0'), ('100', '<---------- ', '30', '0', '0', '0'), ('180', '<---------- ', '12', '0', '0', '18'), ('200', '<---------- ', '12', '0', '0', '0'), ('ACK', '---------->', '12', '0'), ('INFO', '---------->', '12', '0', '0'), ('200', '<---------- ', '12', '0', '0', '0'), ('BYE', '---------->', '12', '0'), ('200', '<---------- ', '12', '0', '0', '0')].
```

I have used below script t get the output.
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
import re

aa = '''
xmlSFT_Client_mscmlivr MSCML_FULL_AUDIO_Script_CA_disabled.
Warning: open file limit > FD_SETSIZE; limiting max. # of open files to FD_SETSIZE = 1024
Resolving remote host '10.214.13.168'... Done.
------------------------------ Scenario Screen -------- [1-9]: Change Screen --
  Call-rate(length)   Port   Total-time  Total-calls  Remote-host
  10.0(0 ms)/1.000s   4063      11.24 s           30  10.214.13.168:5060(UDP)

  Call limit reached (-m 30), 0.000 s period  0 ms scheduler resolution
  0 calls (limit 300)                    Peak was 13 calls, after 1 s
  0 Running, 31 Paused, 0 Woken up
  0 dead call msg (discarded)            0 out-of-call msg (discarded)
  2 open sockets

                                 Messages  Retrans   Timeout   Unexpected-Msg
           INVITE ---------->         30        0         0
              100 <----------         30        0         0         0
              180 <----------         12        0         0         18
              200 <----------         12        0         0         0

              ACK ---------->         12        0
             INFO ---------->         12        0         0
              200 <----------         12        0         0         0
       Pause [         10.0s]         12                            0
              BYE ---------->         12        0
              200 <----------         12        0         0         0

'''

a = []

for i in aa.split('\n'):

    if re.findall(r'^\s+(\w+)\s?(.-+.)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)',i,re.MULTILINE):
            a.append(re.findall(r'^\s+(\w+)\s?(.-+.)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)',i,re.MULTILINE)[0])
    elif re.findall(r'^\s+(\w+)\s?(.-+.)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)',i,re.MULTILINE) :
            a.append(re.findall(r'^\s+(\w+)\s?(.-+.)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)',i,re.MULTILINE)[0])
    elif re.findall(r'^\s+(\w+)\s?(.-+.)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)',i,re.MULTILINE):
            a.append(re.findall(r'^\s+(\w+)\s?(.-+.)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)',i,re.MULTILINE)[0])

print a
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Comment: please use ctrl + k to indent your code block

Comment: There's no question here, just a bunch of code (which still isn't all properly formatted).

Comment: Thanks Yikang for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

So first of all, you haven't format your question well. I try to format it for you but you need more text to explain.

basically from my understanding, the question is having a string `a`:

```
a = '''
  2 open sockets

                                 Messages  Retrans   Timeout   Unexpected-Msg
           INVITE ---------->         30        0         0
              100 <----------         30        0         0         0
              180 <----------         12        0         0         18
              200 <----------         12        0         0         0

              ACK ---------->         12        0
             INFO ---------->         12        0         0
              200 <----------         12        0         0         0
       Pause [         10.0s]         12                            0
              BYE ---------->         12        0
              200 <----------         12        0         0         0

'''
```

you wanted to get all the result like this: `('INVITE', '---------->', '30', '0', '0'),`

I used the following regex line to achieve:

```
import re

a = '''
  2 open sockets

                                 Messages  Retrans   Timeout   Unexpected-Msg
           INVITE ---------->         30        0         0
              100 <----------         30        0         0         0
              180 <----------         12        0         0         18
              200 <----------         12        0         0         0

              ACK ---------->         12        0
             INFO ---------->         12        0         0
              200 <----------         12        0         0         0
       Pause [         10.0s]         12                            0
              BYE ---------->         12        0
              200 <----------         12        0         0         0

'''
pattern = re.compile(r'(?P<type>\d+|\w+)\s*(?P<dir>\<?\-+\>?)\s+(?P<messages>\d*)[\n\r\s]*(?P<retrans>\d*)[\n\r\s]*(?P<timeout>\d*)[\n\r\s]*(?P<unexpected_msg>\d*)\n',flags=re.MULTILINE)
result = pattern.finditer(a)
result_list = [m.groupdict() for m in result]
```

output for result:

```
...:for i in result_list:
    print(i)

...:
{'type': 'INVITE', 'dir': '---------->', 'messages': '30', 'retrans': '0', 'timeout': '0', 'unexpected_msg': ''}
{'type': '100', 'dir': '<----------', 'messages': '30', 'retrans': '0', 'timeout': '0', 'unexpected_msg': '0'}
{'type': '180', 'dir': '<----------', 'messages': '12', 'retrans': '0', 'timeout': '0', 'unexpected_msg': '18'}
{'type': '200', 'dir': '<----------', 'messages': '12', 'retrans': '0', 'timeout': '0', 'unexpected_msg': '0'}
{'type': 'ACK', 'dir': '---------->', 'messages': '12', 'retrans': '0', 'timeout': '', 'unexpected_msg': ''}
{'type': 'INFO', 'dir': '---------->', 'messages': '12', 'retrans': '0', 'timeout': '0', 'unexpected_msg': ''}
{'type': '200', 'dir': '<----------', 'messages': '12', 'retrans': '0', 'timeout': '0', 'unexpected_msg': '0'}
{'type': 'BYE', 'dir': '---------->', 'messages': '12', 'retrans': '0', 'timeout': '', 'unexpected_msg': ''}
{'type': '200', 'dir': '<----------', 'messages': '12', 'retrans': '0', 'timeout': '0', 'unexpected_msg': '0'}
```

then you can iterate the `result_list`.

Instead of using list of tuple as you mentioned in the question, because i think you may wants to know what value is missing. `('ACK', '---------->', '12', '0')` like this may not tell you which 2 value is missing because i saw at line pause there is only message value and unexpected-msg value. 
`Pause [         10.0s]         12                            0`

hope this is what you are looking for and please add more description to the question so that you can format your code nicely.